# Retrieve just one column from MySQL query results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a series of links from data pulled from a database.

Here is the query I am running:

```
<?php
$result = $db->query("SELECT imageurl FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%$id%' OR title LIKE '%$id%' OR category LIKE '%$id%' LIMIT 0, 15");
while($row = $result->fetch_row())
{
echo '<a href="'.print_r($row).'">'.$row.'</a>'.'<br />';
} ?>
```

The column "imageurl" contains a full URL to an image. Note that I am using ProcessWire CMS, which is where the unique query references come from.

The resulting output returns the correct entries from the database.  The search works.  However, they are literally a series of lines like this:

```
Array ( [0] => http://imagesource.net/graphics/product_images/pACE3-8573838t212.jpg ) Array
```

The word "array" at the end contains a hyperlink, but it does not link to the correct URL.

I'm sure it's an obvious error. Can anyone point out what's wrong?

Comment: Currently you are printing an array instead getting the string value you are looking for.

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_row  the mysql/mysqli functions return an **ARRAY**. and print_r() does NOT return its dump, it does immediately output, so your echo/concat operation is wrong.

Comment: Matthew, don't forget to tick the answer that most helped you `:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</a>'.'<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  It not only solved this problem, but also taught me something.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
echo '<a href="'.print_r($row).'">'.$row.'</a>'.'<br />';
```

to:

```
echo '<a href="'.$row['imageurl'].'">'.$row['imageurl'].'</a>'.'<br />';
```

or:

```
echo '<a href="'.$row['imageurl'].'">'.basename($row['imageurl']).'</a>'.'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row())
{
  echo '<a href="'.print_r($row[0]).'">'.$row[0].'</a>'.'<br />';
} ?>
```

Comment: You don't need the `print_r` at all, in fact - just the `$row[0]`. `:)`.